# Qual é o valor máximo para Number em javascript?

Tags: javascript

No PHP, temos um limit para os valores do tipo `int`, que é demonstrado pela constante `PHP_INT_MAX`.

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX; // Imprime: 9223372036854775807
```

E no javascript? Como faço para descobrir o valor máximo aceito para um objeto `Number` (inteiro)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No JS essa representação se dá assim:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE
```

E seu valor é de aproximadamente 1.79E+308. Ou seja, 179 seguido de 306 algarismos.

Veja o código:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Number.MAX_VALUE;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Fonte: [Number.MAX_VALUE - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE)

Comment: Não me lembro você ter respondido uma pergunta minha antes :). valeu!

Answer (score 6):

No ES6 existe uma constante para verificar o maior inteiro seguro `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, você tambem pode verificar o maior valor permitido usando `Number.MAX_VALUE` , porém vale lembrar que é interessante que não utilize valores não seguros.

Caso execute o Snippet abaixo em um navegador que suporte esta propriedade do ES6, irá ver o maior/menor valor seguro.

```js
var minNumber = document.createElement("div");
var maxNumber = document.createElement("div");
var minSafeNumber = document.createElement("div");
var maxSafeNumber = document.createElement("div");

minNumber.innerHTML = "Number.MIN_VALUE: " + Number.MIN_VALUE;
minSafeNumber.innerHTML = "Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER: " + Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
maxSafeNumber.innerHTML = "Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER: " + Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
maxNumber.innerHTML = "Number.MAX_VALUE: " + Number.MAX_VALUE;

document.body.appendChild(minNumber);
document.body.appendChild(minSafeNumber);
document.body.appendChild(maxSafeNumber);
document.body.appendChild(maxNumber);
```

Answer (score 5):

Atente para o fato de que existem dois "números máximos". Um é o maior número de ponto flutuante, que as demais respostas apontaram corretamente (Number.MAX_VALUE, 1.79E+308).

O outro é o maior número **inteiro** que pode ser representado sem ambiguidade, que é um valor de 16 dígitos (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ou 2 elevado a 53a potência menos 1). Este patamar é importante para programas que precisam fazer contas exatas, como sistemas financeiros.

Acima deste patamar, adicionar valores pequenos a um número grande não funciona mais direito:

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
9007199254740991
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2
9007199254740992
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 3
9007199254740994
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 4
9007199254740996
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 5
9007199254740996
```

Outra forma de entender este problema é: em ponto flutuante, a precisão só é mantida numa soma se os dois números somados tiverem diferença de magnitude não maior que 15 dígitos.